# why the server sent events connection always contain error output

Tags: java, typescript, server-sent-events

I am using the server sent events to push some data from server side to client side, this is the client side typescript code looks like:

```
export function doSseChatAsk(params: ChatAsk, onSseMessage: (msg: string) => void,) {
  let eventSource: EventSourcePolyfill;
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("x-access-token");
  var queryString = Object.keys(params).map(key => key + '=' + params[key as keyof ChatAsk]).join('&');
  eventSource = new EventSourcePolyfill('/ai/stream/chat/ask?' + queryString, {
    headers: {
      'x-access-token': accessToken ?? "",
      'x-request-id': uuid(),
    }
  });
  eventSource.onopen = () => {
    
  }
  eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
    console.log("onerror",error)
    if(eventSource){
      eventSource.close();
    }
  }
  eventSource.onmessage = e => {
    onSseMessage(e.data);
  };

  eventSource.addEventListener('complete', () => {
    console.log('Transfer of data is complete');
  });
  
  eventSource.addEventListener('onclose', () => {
    console.log('Transfer of data is complete');
  });
}
```

everything works fine, but now I found the client always running into onerror code block, this is the error output(the text copied is not readable so I am paste the image):

[image]

I hava no clue where is going wrong, this is my server side java code:

```
public SseEmitter askStream(String prompt, Long cid) {
        final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(120000L);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(prompt.trim())) {
            throw GlobalException.PARAM_VERIFY_EXCEPTION;
        }
        Long vipExpireTime = RequestContext.getVipExpireTime();
        if (vipExpireTime == null || vipExpireTime <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            freeUserChat(emitter, prompt, cid);
        } else {
            askStreamImpl(emitter, prompt, cid);
        }
        return emitter;
    }
```

is it possible to fixed this issue?

Comment: stuck in the same thing, everything ends fine but sse is always sending error